# TypeScript: typing a function that takes a newable object when strict function types are enabled

Tags: typescript

Using TypeScript with strict function types enabled, I am trying to express a function `create` that takes a newable object that itself takes an `IService` argument:

```
interface IService { }

interface Constructible<T> {
    new(service: IService): T;
}

declare function create<T>(ctor: Constructible<T>): void;
```

I then want to call `create` with a `Manager` class that takes a more specific version of `IService` in its constructor

```
interface RequestService extends IService {
    makeRequest(): void;
}

class Manager {
    constructor(requestService: RequestService) { }
}

create<Manager>(Manager);
```

This does work with strict function types enabled. The error on the call to `create` is:

```
Argument of type 'typeof Manager' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Constructible<Manager>'.
  Types of parameters 'requestService' and 'service' are incompatible.
    Property 'makeRequest' is missing in type 'IService' but required in type 'RequestService'.
```

Why does this error happen and can I express this pattern without using casts and without inlining the types?

---

The one workaround that I know does work is to inline `Constructible` and use `extends`:

```
declare function create<T, S extends IService>(ctor: { new(service: S): T; }): void;
```

Unfortunately it does not work if I try the same with the extracted interface:

```
interface Constructible<T> {
    new<S extends IService>(service: S): T;
}
```

Comment: A `Constructible<Manager>` must be a constructor that accepts any `IService` as an argument (e.g., `new ctor({})` must behave well).  But `Manager` is not a `Constructible<Manager>`, since `new Manager({})` is an error (`{}` is an `IService` but not a `RequestService`).  So the error is, at first glance, a good one.  What does `create()` do with the constructor you pass it?  Does it actually call the constructor?   If so, what does it pass it?

Comment: In the non-example version of this code, the implementation of `create` ensures that `new` is called  with the type the constructor itself expects (`RequestService` in this case).

Comment:  How does it do that?  Is there some mapping somewhere from constructor to required argument type that is available at runtime?  You might want to augment your example code a bit to show this.  Maybe there's something the type system can use to tighten your `Constructible` definition in the proper way.

Comment: How `create` is implemented isn't really relevant to this question; assume it's implemented by an external library and we need to write the typings for it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell you to type it without some better idea of what it's doing.  Right now it seems like something that takes any constructor as an argument, and then *somehow* has the right argument to call that constructor with.  If `create()` took another argument corresponding to the constructor's required parameter type, or if the constructor itself had a static property corresponding to this type, I could imagine how it's done and how it should be typed.  But right now it seems impossible.  I assume you don't want `new (service: any): T`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your workaround is basically the way to go. With the info provided (and as jcalz mentions more info might produce a better suggestion from us) I would suggest putting `S` on the `Constructible` type not the constructor signature. From what I can see in the example the implementing class itself is not generic (ie. it can't take any `S` desired by the caller, it takes a specific `S` determined by the class declaration)

```
interface IService { }

interface Constructible<T, S extends IService> {
    new(service: S): T;
}

declare function create<T, S extends IService>(ctor: Constructible<T, S>, service: S): void;

interface RequestService extends IService {
    makeRequest(): void;
}

class Manager {
    constructor(requestService: RequestService) { }
}

create(Manager, {
  makeRequest() { }
});
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGVoDdhOQb2QF8AoE0SWRFAYQHsQBnMKAVwTGACMAbCAHgAqAGmTpkEAB6QQAE0ZpMUHEgB8BEsi3IQEAO4AKRtlwQAXGICUFwQG4SpErIgIecKChisQHYA2QIHnCQQqLiUjLyiiZqBhx0UBb0TCzsnLwCImKqosbKphbo1shYdMCy9uTg0PB4AEoQAI6sEMxKKigREHIKGDEo+JraALZwANYQDc2tYAbFpeX2jq5wjAoAsnAgcADm0BraAQzMbPFQBh7Tbf0WUy3X+UiWBMQOZIEQwRAGm9t7UKJBlpRhM7jM5i9SERLLYgA)

I also added a parameter of the service type to the `create` function. Not sure how you ensure the service parameter is right in your actual code, but this seems like something the caller needs to know not the implementation.